# Autorouting based on Taxonomies in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I created a custom content type called ContentPage and attached a taxonmy field (Taxo). I'm trying to have the autoroute generate the route off the Taxonomy term selected for ContentPage.  The end result should be http://my-site.com/taxonomy/term/slug

Here is one of the rules I tried:  {Content.Fields.ContentPage.Taxo}/{Content.Slug}

Whatever I try, I only get the slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked in many occassions. you need to look at the way the slug is created and get a token too.
Check This out, will help : [taxonomy-term-autoroute](http://sheltonial.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/orchard-cms-taxonomy-term-autoroute.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I went with {Content.Fields.ContentPage.Taxo.Terms:0.Path}/{Content.Slug}